# K&R - The C programming language Exercise1-12

Tags: c

I am working through the K&R and just finished exercise 1-12 and below is my solution.
Exercise1-12: Write a program that prints input one word per line.

```
#include <stdio.h>


main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' ||  c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        {
            putchar('\n');
            while(c == ' '|| c == '\t' || c == '\n')
             c = getchar();
        }
        putchar(c); 
    }
}
```

My question is both author and solutions [here](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_12) defined and used the state variable.
when we compare my solution is pretty simple but it works. am I missing something? maybe there is a case that my solution won't work well?

Looking for your comments to improve, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a historically correct impression of programming in C, K&R is probably the best book available. In addition to that book, you should also get a more modern book about C since K&R doesn't teach you anything about function prototypes and buffer overflows (one of the main reasons that software written in C is often unreliable).

For example, [the page you linked](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_12) has a solution containing `char buffer[1024];`. That solution will fail with unpredictable behavior as soon as you pass it a file containing very long words, as the buffer will overflow and the C program will not reliably crash but is free to do anything it wants, including crashing or making daemons fly out of your nose. This is called [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There's not much to improve about your code. To make it modern, you simply have to replace one line:

```
main()              // before
int main(void)      // after
```

After that, you should tell your editor to *format the source code*. This will indent the innermost line `c = getchar()` a bit more, so that it is clearly inside the `while` loop.

```
// before:
while(c == ' '|| c == '\t' || c == '\n')
 c = getchar();

// after:
while (c == ' '|| c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    c = getchar();
```

Some other reviewers will say that you *must always use braces* in the `if` and `while` statements, but I disagree. It's enough to let your editor or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) format the source code automatically, this will make it obvious when your code is indented wrongly.

Comment: What about ctype.h and isspace(int c)?

Comment: Indeed, that would have been simpler.